# Animating elements that are repositioned from window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am creating a web page that contains lots of transitions and animations. I don't like it when things zap from one place to another, I like it to slide over instead. Which is why I have a problem with responsive web apps. Yes, the elements of the page will reposition themselves correctly when you resize the window, but they don't animate, instead they go from point A to point B in, quite literally, no time.

Is there any way I can solve this problem? I am open to any CSS or JS solutions. For an example, go [here](https://goo.gl/pr8X4y), make your browser window smaller, and click on the hamburger menu icon in the top left. The buttons in the main section of the page reposition themselves but again, no animation. It makes me sad.

Comment: How are they supposed to animate? Unless you write code for the animation, the browser can't read your mind.

Comment: I suppose if it was a browser feature, just a simple linear translation. As for the transition time, that could be a default value, maybe 200ms. But is there any sort of JavaScript code that I can write to automate this?

Comment: Instead of animating the buttons, why not just write some CSS that makes them responsive so they collapse nicely?

Comment: @BuzzotheSplitter How does one do that?